# How to change SQL Server Express instance from 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express, however, when I query `select @@version`, it returns SQL Server 2008 instance, how can I change the SQL Server Express to run on instance 2012?

I installed Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 Express was installed at the same time. But now I installed SQL Server 2012 Express, I need to use this newer version to restore some databases.

Comment: What **instance name** did you give your SQL Server 2012 Express when you installed it? Just use that instance name to connect to it: use  `servername\instancename` as your server name.

Comment: Your edit sounds to me like a resolution of the particular issue you were asking about. It would probably make sense to post it as an answer (and ultimately accept it too).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your service:

[image]

And then connect to the SQL Server 2012 version using

```
.\SQL2012
```

Also use this query to check the correct version number:

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that change IP Address of SQL Server Instance protocol. In order to do use following steps:

1. Run SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Select SQL Server Network configuration
3. Select protocols for your Instance (2008 / 2012 ,...)
4. select TCP/IP Item
5. Select IP Addresses tab
6. Change IP Addresses of SQL Server 2008 Instance with SQL Server 2012 Instance IP Address

   and change IP Address of SQL Server 2012 Instance with SQL Server 2008 Instance IP Address
7. Restart Database Engine 2008 and 2012

Answer (score 0):

**I answer my own question to help those encounter the same issue in future**

I made a mistake, I noticed that I only have SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but I don't have running instance. What I downloaded and installed is `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU`, but what I need to install is `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU`.